# Wordpress: Images not rendering on the site

Tags: php, wordpress, image, windows-hosting

I'm working on a client wordpress website with a custom theme. The problem is that images are not rendering on the website (eg. Logo, slider images, etc). I've checked the media library and whenever I'm trying to access the image URLs it says 500 internal server error. The website is hosted on a Windows server (XAMPP) and has IIS 7.

The website was actually running fine until i noticed that by default the url had **index.php** in it for all the website links (Eg. http://example.com/index.php/about-us/vision-and-mission/, http://example.com/index.php/core-values/, etc ). I later discovered that in the permalinks, they were using custom links with **index.php** in it so I just changed the custom structure to postname which actually broke it all.

I've checked the images in the server and they are present there at the very URL but somehow its not coming up on the frontend.

PS: This is .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: share the link to your website for the better understanding of the problem.

Comment: @abrar Sorry can't do that. Its a client project! Can help you with anything else?

Comment: What's wrong with this statement `Windows server and has IIS 7` and `This is .htaccess file`,  IIS does not natively support mod rewrite (.htaccess), which is an Apache module so they no workie together.  Granted there are things you can do to make them work together or get something "like" mod rewrite, but that's not really a topic I care to cover as there are plenty of things on the web that can do it better them me.  But if you are saying you changed the links to be rewritten and `actually broke it all` is that a surprise when the server (IIS) doesn't support rewriting with .htaccess?